# For street network data lacking z-elevation information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-dataset

Can anyone help me in this? Many street network datasets lack z elevation fields needed to model overpass and tunnels (the *F_ZLEV* and *T_ZLEV* fields). Although my road network spatial database contains bridges and tunnels as features, I need to create the two fields from it. Is there a quick fix to automate this. I am thinking of something like:

- Select all road links and allocate *F_ZLEV*=0 and *T_ZLEV*=0
- Select all bridges which at their link start connect to road link and allocate *F_ZLEV*=0 and *T_ZLEV*=1
- Select all bridges which at their link end connect to road link and allocate *F_ZLEV*=1 and *T_ZLEV*=0
- Allocate all other bridge links *F_ZLEV*=1 and *T_ZLEV*=1.

Any ideas will help.